# WinApi сообщения

Tags: winapi, delphi

Помогите пожалуйста!

1. Необходимо обеспечить запись в один файл клавиатурные сообщения, приходящие моему окну.
2. Учтите тот факт, что приложение может быть запущено много раз и всё равно запись должна осуществляться в один файл.

С первой частью я справился, помогите, если сможете, со второй:

```
program Project4;

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils;

var
  WndClass: TWndClass;
  szAppName, buf: PChar;
  WinHandle: HWnd;
  Msg: TMsg;
  hFile: THandle;
  number: cardinal;
  ch: char;
  nice: boolean;

function MyWndProc(hwnd: hwnd; msg: UINT; wparam: wparam; lparam: lparam): longint;stdcall;
begin
  case Msg of
     WM_KEYDOWN:
    begin
      writefile(hFile, ' WM_KEYDOWN ',13, number, nil);
    end;

   WM_KEYUP:
    begin
      writefile(hFile, ' WM_KEYUP ',10, number, nil);
    end;

  WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
    begin
      writefile(hFile, ' WM_SYSKEYDOWN ',16, number, nil);
    end;

  WM_SYSKEYUP:
    begin
      writefile(hFile, ' WM_SYSKEYUP ',14, number, nil);
    end;

  WM_CHAR:
    begin
       writefile(hFile, ' WM_CHAR ',9, number, nil);
    end;

  WM_DEADCHAR:
   begin
      writefile(hFile, ' WM_DEADCHAR ',13, number, nil);
   end;

 WM_SYSCHAR:
    begin
      writefile(hFile, ' WM_SYSCHAR ',12, number, nil);
    end;

 WM_SYSDEADCHAR:
    begin
       writefile(hFile, ' WM_SYSDEADCHAR ',16, number, nil);
    end;

    WM_DESTROY:
      begin
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        Result := 0;
      end;
   { WM_CHAR:
      begin
        ch := chr(wparam);
        writefile(hFile, ch, sizeof(ch) * SizeOf(Char), number, nil);
        Result := 0;
      end; }
    else Result := DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
  end;
end;

begin
  szAppName := 'Hello windows.';
  WndClass.style := CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW;
  WndClass.lpfnWndProc := @MyWndProc;
  WndClass.cbClsExtra := 0;
  WndClass.cbWndExtra := 0;
  WndClass.hInstance := hInstance;
  WndClass.hIcon := LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
  WndClass.hCursor := LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
  WndClass.hbrBackground := CreateSolidBrush($FFFFFF);
  WndClass.lpszMenuName := nil;
  WndClass.lpszClassName := szAppName;
  RegisterClass(WndClass);
  WinHandle := CreateWindow(WndClass.lpszClassName, 'Окно',
                                                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                                    400,
                                                    400,
                                                    550,
                                                    250,
                                                    0,
                                                    0,
                                                    hInstance,
                                                    nil);
  ShowWindow(WinHandle, SW_SHOW);
  UpdateWindow(WinHandle);
  hFile := CreateFile('myfile.txt', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
                  0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

  while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do
    begin
      TranslateMessage(Msg);
      DispatchMessage(Msg);
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы обеспечить вторую часть, вы учитывайте про синхронизацию своих процессов. Вам необходимо файл поместить в критическую секцию или можно создать событие, которые показывает могут ли сейчас писать в файл или нет, или мьютекс, или семафор, ...